# User can only select from first column of checkboxes, using the column-count css property

Tags: html, css

I have a form where user's can select one or more options from a list via checkboxes. They are broken up into multiple columns using the column-count CSS property. This works fine for me in all browsers (I am on windows), but my colleague using a Mac and Chrome has an issue where he can only select from the first column of items. Why might this be happening and what could be done?

```
<div id="div_id_step_three-amenities" class="control-group"><label for="id_step_three-amenities" class="control-label">
            Amenities: 
        </label><div class="controls"><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_1" value="5">A/V Equipment
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_2" value="8">Catering Available
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_3" value="11">Full Bar
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_4" value="20">Rooftop
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_5" value="1">Pool
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_6" value="2">WiFi
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_7" value="3">Rooms Available
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_8" value="6">Valet Parking
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_9" value="7">Street Parking
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_10" value="9">Outside Catering
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_11" value="10">BYOB
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_12" value="12">Beer/Wine Only
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_13" value="13">No Drinking Allowed
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_14" value="16">Kosher
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_15" value="17">Spa
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_16" value="18">Indoor
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_17" value="19">Outdoor
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_18" value="21">Handicap Accessible
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_19" value="22">Smoking
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_20" value="23">Non-Smoking
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_21" value="24">Non-Union
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_22" value="25">Coat Check
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_23" value="26">Great Views
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_24" value="27">Theater
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_25" value="28">Media Room
    </label><label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_26" value="29">Beachfront
    </label></div></div>

        .wizard #div_id_step_three-event_type .controls, .wizard #div_id_step_three-amenities .controls {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 0;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 0;
        column-count: 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [for attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) to your labels, example:

```
<label class="checkbox inline" for="id_step_three-amenities_2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="step_three-amenities" id="id_step_three-amenities_2" value="8">Catering Available
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because of you missed `column-gap`

it should be in this below values

```
column-gap: 3px
column-gap: 2.5em
column-gap: normal    
column-gap: inherit
```

**reference link**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap

```
.wizard #div_id_step_three-event_type .controls, .wizard #div_id_step_three-amenities .controls {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap:normal;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: normal;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap:normal;
    }
```

Comment: I a still having this issue even after trying these values. It turns out to only be affecting IOS in the Chrome browser...

Comment: Also I noticed if you click the empty space below the first column it will actually select the checkbox in the second. As if the checkbox is triggered from that location, but the label and input are rendered correctly in the second column.